# Date Format not accepted in SQl

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, date-format

I have Query Like this

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM attendance_entry WHERE absent_date="Fri Feb 20 00:00:00 IST 2015";
```

In Mysql absent_date is in these format(yyyy-mm-dd).

When I am using Hiberante Criteria it accepts. How to write Query?

Comment: MySQL accepts this kind of date format: `2015-02-19 22:14:52 `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works Perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM attendance_entry 
WHERE absent_date=STR_TO_DATE('Fri Feb 20 00:00:00 IST 2015','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s IST %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the java `Date` object into the `sql` accepting format, then pass this to your sql query.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // or "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
Date today = new Date(); 
System.out.println(today); // Fri Feb 13 14:42:01 IST 2015
String fomattedDate = sdf.format(today);
System.out.println(fomattedDate); // 2015-02-13

// pass fomattedDate to sql
String sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance_entry WHERE absent_date="+fomattedDate";
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know is .

1.Which format you are using & what is the format type you have used while creating table.

2.You can see this by type desc "tablename"

3.Are you using any specified region for timestamp,region (i.e: china,india,america, like that).
by finding it that you can do.

I just create a table with timestamp,
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SSXFF';

Session altered.

SQL> CREATE TABLE table_ts(c_id NUMBER, c_ts TIMESTAMP);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO table_ts VALUES(1, '01-JAN-2003 2:00:00');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO table_ts VALUES(2, TIMESTAMP '2003-01-01 4:00:00');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from table_ts where c_ts='01-JAN-03 04:00:00.000000';

### C_ID

### C_TS

```
     3
```

01-JAN-03 04:00:00.000000